# ошибка: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Вылезает ошибка при запуске одного из элементов кода. Почему то он пытается найти колонку, но хотя должен найти в колонке строку с названием из `get_card`, не очень понимаю в чем ошибка

```py
def regural(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    user_id = message.chat.id
    cur.execute('SELECT regular FROM users WHERE user_id = ("%s")' % user_id)
    users = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    cards_regural = ['`219sj`', '`25bmw320d`', '`26bmwx3`', '`1991ft`', '`22mbc2k`', '`202vc`', '`221he20mpi`',
                     '`27bmw120i`',
                     '`213m3`', '`1998fmst200`', '`216ho`', '`1996aslx`', '`210coltz`', '`215mbgla220d`', '`207mitlan`',
                     '`2p206cc`', '`2blse`', '`191v96030`', '`199hc`', '`213vs60`', '`20chebla`', '`213hs20t`',
                     '`216ff10`',
                     '`26chemat`', '`28volsha`', '`217fiti`', '`27renalag`', '`217voltroc`', '`213nisno`',
                     '`215volsha`',
                     '`217fiat500`', '`23volgol`', '`212miout`', '`212toycor`', '`27mitcolt`', '`24mba150`',
                     '`211tc20`',
                     '`26niq16`', '`24niti16`', '`25ninote`']
    get_card = random.choice(cards_regural)
    cur.execute('SELECT {} FROM user_regular_card WHERE user_id={}'.format(get_card, user_id))
    card = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    for card_user in card:
        if card_user[0] == 0:
            for card_rarity in users:
                if card_rarity[0] == 0:
                    cur.execute('UPDATE users SET regular=? WHERE user_id=?', ('1', user_id))
                    cur.execute('UPDATE user_regular_card SET {} = 1 WHERE user_id={}'.format(get_card, user_id))
                    cur.execute('SELECT image, card_name FROM regular_card WHERE short_name={}'.format(get_card, ))
                    cards = cur.fetchall()
                    conn.commit()
                    for card in cards:
                        bot.send_photo(user_id, open(card[0], 'rb'), caption=f'Вам выпала карточка - <i>{card[1]}</i>',
                                       parse_mode='Html')
                elif card_rarity[0] == 1:
                    cur.execute('UPDATE user_regular_card SET {} = 1 WHERE user_id={}'.format(get_card, user_id))
                    cur.execute('SELECT image, card_name FROM regular_card WHERE short_name={}'.format(get_card, ))
                    cards = cur.fetchall()
                    conn.commit()
                    for card in cards:
                        bot.send_photo(user_id, open(card[0], 'rb'), caption=f'Вам выпала карточка - <i>{card[1]}</i>',
                                       parse_mode='Html')
        elif card_user[0] == 1:
            regural(message)

    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Ошибка:

```py
    cur.execute('SELECT image, card_name FROM regular_card WHERE short_name={}'.format(get_card, ))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: 210coltz
```

Comment: Покажите состав таблицы `regular_card` из базы данных

Comment: Проблема только с данной картой или со всеми?

Comment: CREATE TABLE regular_card (
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                        NOT NULL
                        UNIQUE,
    short_name  TEXT    UNIQUE
                        NOT NULL
                        DEFAULT (0),
    image       TEXT    UNIQUE
                        NOT NULL
                        DEFAULT (0),
    card_name   TEXT    NOT NULL,
    year        INTEGER,
    description TEXT
);

Comment: @Forv Проблема состоит со всеми картами, regural - одна из редкостей, таких еще 8 таблиц разных редкостей и везде почему то вместо того, чтобы найти строку с названием карточки из переменной - он пытается найти столбец с названием карточки из переменной

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашёл у вас проблему. Вы не обернули кавычками `{}`, а в `SQL` без них никак:) Нужно так:

```
cur.execute("SELECT image, card_name FROM regular_card WHERE short_name='{}'".format(get_card, ))
```

---

##### UPD:

Ну или так (не проверял, но должно работать):

```
cur.execute("SELECT image, card_name FROM regular_card WHERE short_name={}".format(f"get_card", ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь возможна только одна причина - столбец `210coltz` в таблице `regular_card` *действительно не существует.*

Может быть, что вы хотели этот столбец взять из **другой таблицы**, или что в имени `210coltz` **опечатка**.

Comment: я же написал, что он не является колонкой, а наоборот является данным в колонке short_name

Comment: Моя ошибка. :-(